# Flutter Error too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter

I could not figure out why this error happened and how to solve this. Here is the code. Error is from the top to the line before center Widget. I thought () or [] might not be enough or something but I could not figure it out. If there is any tips about solving this type of errors, I would like to know them too. Thank you.

```
Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          Spacer(),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_add),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Center(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.grade,
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: You missed a closing parentheses and comma on the 6th row, to close the Container

Comment: Is the row supposed to be a child of the container?

Comment: Line 7: add ``child: Row(.....``

Answer (score 0):

i solved the same error with deleting the row inside the row
so don't write a row tag inside a row tag or you will face this error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).